# Showing a Specific List Item in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I'm trying to display the second element added to my list. The list is filled inside a controller, named `HomeController`:

The list elements are added in the HomeController, inside a foreach cycle. They are obtained from a XML file.

```
tagsGroup.Add(...
{
    Name = node.Attributes["Name"].Value,
    Label = node.Attributes["Label"].Value,
    Description = node.Attributes["Description"].Value
});
```

Then, in my View I try to fetch a specific list element like so:

```
<table class="table" id="container_attribute_group_secondary">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>

@foreach(myApp.Controllers.HomeController.TagsModel.TagsGroup.tagsGroup in Model.TagsGroup)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@tagsGroup.Name.[1]</td>
        <td>@tagsGroup.Label.[1]</td>
        <td>@tagsGroup.Description.[1]</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Note: `TagsGroup` is `IENumerable`

But what I get from this code is just a letter, the nth letter depending on the number I put. Alternatively, I tried this, only to get the same result (shows the first letter):

```
<td>@tagsGroup.Name.First()</td>
<td>@tagsGroup.Label.First()</td>
<td>@tagsGroup.Description.First()</td>
```

I might be mixing things up as I am kind of rusty on lists and arrays, so I'm hoping someone can explain me whats wrong, and what I should do.

Comment: Just remove the .[1] from each <td>. The foreach gives you a tagsgroup object and you are using the indexer [] to look at each string rather than the full property

Comment: Leaving the foreach might have confused my question, I want to display only one string. Without the foreach I can't access the values, I'm trying to replace it and I'll edit the post once I do.

Comment: What do you want to occur if there is only one item in your `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to display the second element added to your list, then you don't need a loop. Remove your `foreach` loop and simply use `index`, but since the `TagsGroup` is `IENumerable` and because the `IEnumerable<T>` interface does not include an indexer, you can use [`ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx), something like this:

```
if (1 < @Model.TagsGroup.Count())
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.TagsGroup.ElementAt(1).Name</td>
        <td>@Model.TagsGroup.ElementAt(1).Label</td>
        <td>@Model.TagsGroup.ElementAt(1).Description</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Also not that I have added a check to handle `Index out of range` error that is good for when *there is only one item in your `IEnumerable`*.

Comment: Yes, the loop is unnecessary. I tried using that but it gives me a error saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression to an expression of type  'System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable<...>". I already edited the post, not used to posting questions and I sometimes forget some details.

Comment: @BlindRoach Because the `IEnumerable<T>` interface does not include an indexer, you can use `ElementAt`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BlindRoach If you need to index the `TagGroup` you should think about changing it to a `List` instead of a `IEnumerable`

Comment: @S.Akbari I didn't have the privelege when I asked the question, and it was kind of annoying to see my votes vanishing (even if they say they're later added). There you go